# Sequelize self referencing hasMany does not create alias functions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating a self referencing hasMany relation using this simple piece of code:

```
Story.hasMany(models.Story, {
 as: {singular: 'parent', plural: 'children'},
 foreignKey: 'fk_parent'
});
```

As you can see, the story entity can have multiple story entity children. Using that piece of code I would expect sequelize to create two functions on each story model instance:

```
story.getParent();
story.getChildren();
```

But it doesn't.

hasMany is definitely called, because my table does contain the fk.

Let's assume I have a story with id = 1 and fk_parent = 2. As far as I understand getChildren() should return all stories with fk_parent = 1 and getParent() should return the story with the id = 2. Am I correct or do I get something substantially wrong?

What am I doing wrong?

My complete model is:

```
class Story extends Model {
    static tableName = 'Story';

    static associate(models) {
        Story.hasMany(models.Story, {
            as: {singular: 'parent', plural: 'children'},
            foreignKey: 'fk_parent'
        });
        Story.hasMany(models.Story, {
            as: {singular: 'original', plural: 'reprints'},
            foreignKey: 'fk_reprint'
        });

        Story.belongsTo(models.Issue, {foreignKey: 'fk_issue'});
        Story.belongsToMany(models.Individual, {through: models.Story_Individual, foreignKey: 'fk_story', unique: false});
        Story.belongsToMany(models.Appearance, {through: models.Story_Appearance, foreignKey: 'fk_story'});
    }

export default (sequelize) => {
    Story.init({
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            default: ''
        },
        number: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        pages: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        addinfo: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: ''
        }
    }, {
        indexes: [{
            unique: true,
            fields: ['fk_issue', 'fk_parent', 'addinfo', 'number']
        }],
        sequelize,
        tableName: Story.tableName
    });

    return Story;
};
```

Comment: Do you expect these two functions should be static in Story or be in an Story model instance after you'll get it using some Sequelize query?

Comment: And keep in mind that both aliases are for `Many`-side Story model. So it's confusing to name them opposite `parent - children`. I propose `child - children`.

Comment: They should be in an instance. :) I'll clarify that above.

Comment: And what additional functions do you see in a Story model instance at all? None?

Comment: Excatly. None. :( Let's assume I have a story with ID 1. As far as I understand getChildren() should return all stories with fk_parent = 1 and getParent() should return an story instance with the ID of fk_parent. Correct?

Comment: In that case I have only one suggestion: you didn't call `Story.hasMany` that's why Story instance has no additional methods at all.

Comment: The FK is created in my table, so I would say it is definitely called.

Comment: No. Plural and singular aliases are only needed to create methods to work with 'Many' model. For instance: addChild - adds one child, addChildren - adds several children and so on

Comment: Add a model definition to your post as well

Comment: If you wish to get `parent` record you have to declare one more association: Story.belongTo(models.Story, {
 as: 'parent',
 foreignKey: 'fk_parent'
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222134/discussion-between-christian-riese-and-anatoly).

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the `Story.belongsTo(models.Story, { as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'fk_parent' });`. Thanks to Anatoly!